# Android Scroll view content

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I want to draw my `ScrollView` on whole screen and `ScrollView` content should be display on the whole screen
But I also want to show my ad on bottom of the screen. I have confusion here I just want to give `ScrollView` a
Height something like **(Fill parent - 20 px)** and my ads should be display at (20 PX) at the bottom of the screen
**Note that whatever in the scroll view it should be display on whole screen except (20 px ) of the bottom.**

Comment: post some design how you want and the xml of the layout

Comment: Lolx Boss. what a conclusion  dear....  @Me Malik [ I think i made my situation clear.Let me know if there is any confusion ] :-p very funny

Comment: Give us the more description please

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <!-- Page content  -->

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So `adView` will take fixed 20 dip portion and remaining part will be taken by `ScrollView`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: and what about the scroll view content ? it should be display on rest of the screen I can't upload an Image otherwise I can make you clear easily ... But whats happening is  the 60% height of the screen is taking by Scroll view and 20% is taking by ads and other 20% is free just because of scroll view content .. I just want that 20% which is taking by ads other 80% should be covered by scroll view.

Comment: If you give `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to ScrollView, it should take 80% part. @MeMalik

Comment: In case, you still face problem, then post your xml code in question and upload screenshot on http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/ and paste a link. @MeMalik

Answer (score 0):

use this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="sample button" />

    </LinearLayout>



        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/myscroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/your_ad_layout"
            >
        </>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

All 3 current answers use a RelativeLayout as the root element of the layout, this is bad for performance.

Use a FrameLayout instead, then to make your ScrollView fill_parent - 20px, set its height to fill_parent and its layout_marginBottom to 20px. Set the Ad View to layout_gravity="bottom" and its height to 20px.

In addition, you should make this 20px 20dp, move it into a values/dimens.xml file, and use this same value for the two parameter mentioned above. It's then easy to define different sizes per screen size/density.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9766031373541061/3761995838"
            app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```